# Rounding up decimals Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python pandas and I am having difficulties trying to round up all the values in the column as there is a white space between the decimal point and zero. For example,

```
       Hi
       21. 0
       8. 0
       52. 0
       45. 0
```

I tried using my current code below, but it gave me:

> invalid literal for float(): 21. 0

```
       df.Hi.astype(float).round()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `replace` on the string to replace all whitespace in the string before converting to a float:

```
df.Hi.str.replace(' ', '').astype(float).round()
```

Comment: It returns  "cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>"

Comment: Made an edit to this answer with the correct syntax. Here it is, till the time the edit is approved by @NickEdwards: `df.Hi.str.replace(' ', '').astype(float).round()`

Comment: I don't see your edit request anywhere, but I made the edit myself with your fix - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to convert the values in column `Hi` to `float`.

You have a white space between the decimal points and zeros, which means your values are strings.

You can convert them to `float` using a `lambda` function.

```
df['Hi'] = df['Hi'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(" ", "")).astype(float)
print(df)
    Hi
0  21.0
1   8.0
2  52.0
3  45.0

print(df.dtypes)
Hi    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: I received attribute error: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: I assumed that the `Hi` values were strings because of the white space. So, your values are actually `float`?? What am I missing?

Comment: The datatype is still object, just couldn't convert it to float.

Comment: What do you get when you do `df.dtypes`

Comment: If the `Hi` values are strings, my answer should work.